# Successful login with Custom login page in spring boot starter security not getting to next page

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have been studying spring boot. When using spring-boot-starter-security for a todo application,I tried to login with custom user id and password and custom login page.When I tried login , it is not taking me to next  page. Note : user name is required parameter for next page.

I tried using below but after login it again takes me to login page as error

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/", "/*Todo*/**").access("hasRole('USER')").and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll();
    }
```

This is my securityConfig code

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/listTodo").hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().and()
                .logout().permitAll();
}
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("Sudhakar").password("qwe123").roles("USER","ADMIN");
    }
}

I would need to login with user name and get the todo details of the user who logged in. But I am not able to get to next page, after trying many times I am getting below error

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"

Below is my controller
package com.example.SpringLogin.Controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;

import com.example.SpringLogin.service.loginService;

@Controller
@SessionAttributes("name")
public class LoginController {
    @Autowired
    loginService service;

    @RequestMapping(value="/login",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String loginMessage(ModelMap model,@RequestParam String name,@RequestParam String password) {
        boolean isValidUser=service.validateUser(name, password);

        if(!isValidUser) {
            model.put("message", "Invalid Credentials");
            return"Room";
        }
        model.put("name", name);
        model.put("password",password);

        return "redirect:/todoList";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/login",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String roomLogin(ModelMap model, String error) {
        //model.put("name", name);
        if(error!=null) {
            model.addAttribute("errorMsg","UserName or Password is invalid");
        }
        return "Room";
    }
    /*@RequestMapping(value="/login",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showLogin(ModelMap model) {
        //model.put("name", name);
        return "Welcome";
    }*/
    @RequestMapping(value = "/welcome")
    public String showWelcome(ModelMap model) {
        return "login";
    }
}

My login page

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<c:set var="contextPath" value=""/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link href="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet">
<title>Todo Application</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <font color="red">${message}</font>
        <form:form method="post" action="/login">
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                Name : <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"
                   autofocus="true"/>
                Password: <input type="password" name="password"
                    class="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
            </fieldset>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        </form:form>
    </div>
<script src="webjars/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

After successful login it should go to below page

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<c:set var="contextPath" value=""/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link href="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet">
<title>Todo Application</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

    <table class="table table-striped">
        <H1>Name : ${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name}</H1>

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Course</th>
                <th>End Date</th>
                <th>Is it Done</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${todo}" var="item">
                <tr>
                    <td>${item.id}</td>
                    <td>${item.course}</td>
                    <td><fmt:formatDate value="${item.date}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" /></td>
                    <td>${item.isdone?'Yes':'No'}</td>
                    <td><a type="button" class="btn btn-success"
                        href="/update-Todo?id=${item.id}">Update</a></td>
                    <td><a type="button" class="btn btn-warning"
                        href="/delete-Todo?id=${item.id}">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <div>
        <a type="button" href="/add-Todo" class="btn btn-success">Add a
            Todo</a>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="webjars/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

Service class

package com.example.SpringLogin.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.SpringLogin.model.todoList;

@Service
public class TodoService {

    public static List<todoList> todos=new ArrayList<todoList>();
    public static int todoCount=5;

    static {
        todos.add(new todoList(1, "Sudhakar", "Study history", new Date(), false));
        todos.add(new todoList(2,"Sudhakar","Study geography",new Date(),false));
        todos.add(new todoList(3,"Sudhakar","Study GK",new Date(),false));
        todos.add(new todoList(4,"Mani","Study Java",new Date(),false));
        todos.add(new todoList(5,"Mani","Study script",new Date(),false));
    }

    public List<todoList> retrievetodos(String name){
        List<todoList> retrieved=new ArrayList<todoList>();
        for (todoList todo : todos) {

            if(todo.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                retrieved.add(todo);
            }
        }
        return retrieved;
    }

    public void addTodo(String name,String Course,Date date,boolean isDone) {
        todos.add(new todoList(++todoCount,name,Course,date,isDone));
    }

    public todoList retrieveTodo(int id){

        for (todoList todo : todos) {
            if(todo.getId()==id) {
                return todo;
            }
        }
        return null;        
    }

    public List<todoList> UpdateTodo(todoList todo){
        /*for (todoList td : todos) {
            if(td.getId()==todo.getId()) {
                td.setCourse(todo.getCourse());
                td.setDate(todo.getDate());
            }
        }*/

        todos.remove(todo);
        todos.add(todo);
        return todos;
    }
     //it will delete the todo
    public void deleteTodo(int id) {
        Iterator<todoList> it = todos.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            todoList td=it.next();
            if(td.getId()==id) {
                it.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my expectation is to login application using user name and get the todolist of the user

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `loginProcessUrl` and a `defaultSuccessUrl`. Something like this:

```
.formLogin()
.loginPage("/login")
.loginProcessingUrl("/do_login")
.defaultSuccessUrl("/index")
```

index in this example is the page you want to be taken to upon successful login.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one

```
  .formLogin()
  .loginPage("/login.html")
  .loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login")
  .defaultSuccessUrl("/homepage.html", true)
```